# Seam in JBoss Application Server 7?

Tags: jboss, seam, compatibility

Which Seam framework version is supported in JBoss AS 7?
I am planning to use Seam2.2.2, is it compatible with Jboss AS 7?

Answer (score 17):

Yes and no.

If you visualize yourself the timeline of Seam, the answer comes from alone:

- Seam 2.x was created to ease development against Java EE 5 and to serve as an incubator for future standards, mainly Java EE 6 and JSF 2
- Java EE 6 took the ideas from Seam 2 (and others) to specify CDI (and improve APIs like JSF)
- Seam 3 brings new ideas to Java EE 6 and serves as an incubator for future standards, mainly Java EE 7 and JSF 2.x

**Yes, Seam 2 is - more or less - compatible with JBoss AS 7**. Why? Because Java EE 6 is downwards compatible with Java EE 5. But you will have to deal with some issues, like [this](http://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/07/29/seam-2-booking-example-on-jboss-as-7) and like [that](http://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/07/29/seam-2-booking-example-on-jboss-as-7) one. I just migrated a Seam 2.x application from JBoss AS 4 to JBoss AS 6, and it took me a good deal of a month.

**No, don't use Seam 2 for a new project, not in 2011**. CDI is so much more mature than Seam 2 bijection, JSF 2 is so much easier than JSF 1.2, that any kind of application development will simply be much more fun with Seam 3. And at the end, it's all about having fun at work, or?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.Actually we are planning to deploy a seam 2.2.0 project in JBoss AS7. Currently it is running in JBoss 5.1. While doing that migration there is a confusion in what to go for from below options 1)Seam 2.2.0, 2)Seam 2.2.2, and 3)Seam3 .

Comment: As I said - possible with Seam 2.2.2 (*not* 2.2.0, AFAIK), but work lays ahead. You should do some careful investigations beforehand - the fact that you asked this question implies that this is still an open todo. Whatever motivates the migration to JBoss AS 7, it might be easier and more sophisticated to rewrite the application (or leave it on JBoss 5)

Comment: Anand: keep in mind Seam3 is not Seam2.next it's a completely new implementation like MyFaces CODI.

Comment: I have successfully deployed a Seam 2 app on JBoss AS 7. It took some work, but I learned a lot. Check the forums on jboss.org. Like you, I am used to thinking about "seam app"s. J2EE is a new world and "seam app" is no longer a good way to think of these things.  Better to think about J2EE 6 app. You will probably use a seam module or two, but the heart-and-soul of what we think of when we think "seam app" namely the bridge between JSF and EJB is now implemented by weld.  It's a paradigm shift.  By now, 5 months later, you have probably figured this out.

Comment: Jan: Your two links are the same.

Comment: Oops. Well, it's almost a year since I answered the question and AS 7.1 is out since a while - I'm sure there is more up to date information available in the meantime... :)

Answer (score 2):

I can tell about my experience : we recently migrated a seam 2.2.0 / jsf 1.2 / primefaces 1.1 / jpa 1.0 project on Jboss as 5.1 to seam 2.3.0 CR1 / jsf 2.1 / primefaces 3.4 / jpa 2.0 on Jboss as 7.1.
In fact the seam 2.3 branch was specifically developped to support jsf 2 and it "naturally" targets Jboss as 7.

Our application uses extensively the "Seam Application Framework" and the migration happened to be relatively straightforward, you can check [this](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2012/09/03/seam-230cr1-is-out) for instructions. In the other hand, as it already has been said above, for a new project there should be better alternatives.